# Ui bootstrap pagination, itemsPerPage in custom template?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Anyone tried to show itemsPerPage inside custom template?
Haven't digged source enough but may be not accessible from inside..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ui.bootstrap 1.1.2, custom template can do like:

```
Showing {{pagination.itemsPerPage}} of {{totalItems}}
```